# code ignator update_batch error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

While using `update_batch` function for codeigniter batch update I get this error

> Undefined index: admission_no

[image]

```
function test_update(){
    $updateArray = array();
    $elefee = $this->input->post('effe');
    $extra = $this->input->post('extra');
    $messfe = $this->input->post("messfee");
    $students = $this->Messmodel->get_each_student();

        foreach ($students as $row){
            $newdue = abs($row->amount - ($row->mess_fee + $row->ele_fee + $row->dues));
            $finaldays = ($row->messdays - $row->messcut) * $messfe;
            $messfee = $finaldays + $extra;
            $updateArray[]=array('admission_no'=>$row->ADMISSION_NUMBER,'mess_fee' => $messfee);
        }

    $this->db->update_batch('mess',$updateArray,'admission_no');
}
```

this is my db snap
[image]

When i print update array I get this

[image]

Comment: Can you show your line no 139 from `Messmanager.php` file

Comment: this is my messmanager line 139  $this->db->update_batch('mess',$updateArray,'admission_no');

Comment: Try to debug by adding `echo $this->db->last_query();` after this line 139 and show what query it produced

Comment: Error Number: 1064

UPDATE `mess` SET `admission_no` = CASE WHEN `admission_no` = THEN '16/AE/010' WHEN `admission_no` = THEN '013/AE/006' WHEN `admission_no` = THEN '013/AE/148' WHEN `admission_no` = THEN '013/AE/155' ELSE `admission_no` END, `mess_fee` = CASE WHEN `admission_no` = THEN 3170 WHEN `admission_no` = THEN 3170 WHEN `admission_no` = THEN 3170 WHEN `admission_no` = THEN 3170 ELSE `mess_fee` END WHERE `admission_no` IN(,,,)